What do you call the ''rope'' you move a rolling shutter up and down with in American English?


What do you call the ''rope'' you move a rolling shutter up and down with in American English?

It's misleading to present a picture of a 1 in 1000 flat blind cord. We don't have a special word to distinguish the flat type, and normally the fact that any particular cord happens to be flat wouldn't be of any significance, so we wouldn't bother with the word flat anyway.

You should remove that second picture as it is unrelated to the first and is therefore another question. That second picture is not a picture of the cord used to raise and lower a shutter.

It's called a cord.
'Cord' can just be another word for string, and some might call it that too, but when it activates or controls something, 'cord' is usually the name for it - for example, a pull-cord is the name for the string/cord that activates a light; the cord you pull to open a parachute is a ripcord. You'll see from this website that your specific cord is listed as such.

I see. Thanks. I thought cord was a misnomer because cords and strings are round and thin but the thing in the pictures is flat and relatively wide.

@Z6547 As a material, I think 'cord' is the right name for any length made from multiple strands, woven or overlapping. Electrical wire (which is a conduit for multiple wires within) is also called a cord, particularly on appliances and in US English.

So belt is unnatural?

I'd prefer strap because it's clearly not a cord - in my experience, blinds are usually operated by a thin cord (or a winch or motor), and if there isn't one, you need to make it clear that there's a different mechanism or else people will  be looking for a thin string to pull. Belt would do, but it's probably better to be more explicit: "Pull on the white strap hanging down in the middle".

@Z6547 A belt goes around something - like a belt on a pair of trousers that goes around your waist, or an asteroid belt that circles a planet. If it is a length, then it is a cord.

@StuartF It's definitely not a strap - that, by definition, is a cord or other material that secures or fastens something - there's even the verb to strap [something] down. And yes, some kinds of blinds have different kinds of moving parts such as a wand tilt mechanism for opening the slats, but they often also have a pull cord for raising the blinds altogether. I don't think the OP is looking for the name of alternative mechanisms, just what is pictured.

If it's thin and flat, I'd probably call it a strap too. I think a strap merely needs to be secured to something; it doesn't have to secure it. There are "pull straps".

While the long flat material is still on the roll in bulk, you could call it tape, but once it’s been installed on its mechanism for operating the blinds, then I agree that cord is better.

Ok... Now who should I believe? :-D There seems to be no consensus :-D

@Z6547 I've responed to all the comments. None of these people have submitted answers of their own. I've had 5 upvotes. I've linked to a site that sells these commercially and calls them cords.# Who do you think you should believe?

Yes, they are cords AKA pull cords.

You can draw your own conclusions after considering these two items:

SUMMARY: The U.S. Consumer Product Safety Commission (Commission or CPSC) has determined that custom window coverings with accessible operating cords longer than 8 inches pose an unreasonable risk of strangulation to children 8 years old and younger.Nov 28, 2022

And here's a Google search hit for a sponsored ad from a major
US online retailer:

Blinds With Pull Cords
Wayfair
https://www.wayfair.com › keyword › keyword=blinds...
The cordless operation makes them safe around children and pets. Included strap fasteners make rolling the shade to any desired height easy,
[my emphasis]

So you would have to decide whether you want the term the average speaker might use, or the term the manufacturer might use, for the pull device shown in your photo, which seems to be responding to the USCPSC.

Well, people often just say cord. But I upvoted pull cords here.

Why the emphasis on strap fasteners? Those aren't the things you pull to make the blinds go up and down. Quite the opposite - they're used to make the shade not move by fastening the still-rolled-up part at a particular height.

@NuclearHoagie: According to the description the "strap fasteners make rolling the shade to any desired height easy".

@TimR They make the shade stop at a particular height. They don't make the shade move at all.

@NuclearHoagie   I can't find the picture associated with that text. Maybe it is a special kind of strap fastener that does some "rolling" and is not merely one that secures the blind at a particular height.  The blind has "cordless operation".  But maybe that's like saying of "flip flops" that they have "stringless operation". It's Wayfair, after all.

@TimR I can't imagine why something described as a fastener would actually be intended to make something move. It would make little sense to advertise blinds as "cordless" simply because the cord was large enough to be called a "strap". The defining feature of cordless blinds is that they don't have any dangling apparatus to pull at all.

The 'strap fasteners' referred to in this quotation are not what is pictured in the OP's question. Roman blinds (not Venetian blinds as shown) and some other kinds of gathering blinds may need a strap to fasten them at a given height. Modern Venetian blinds tend to have a locking mechanism to keep their height, usually activated by pulling the cord slightly to one side to unlock and then returning to the original position to lock.

@Astralbee Those don't appear to be venetian blinds.

@TimR ok well then they are roller blinds or shades. They are still made of solid material and wouldn't require 'straps' to hold their height. I think the banding around of terms that are nothing to do with the question is misleading.
